# What's the Enum value difference between 'k' and 'v' in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I just updated the latest Xcode today, when I build my project, the project was occurred an error.
Like this:

```
let playerStatus: BJYPlayerStatus = .playing // ambiguous use of 'playing'
```

The enum defined like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM (NSInteger, BJVPlayerStatus) {
    BJVPlayerStatus_playing,
    // other cases...
    
    BJVPlayerStatus_Playing DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE("use `BJVPlayerStatus_playing`") =
        BJVPlayerStatus_playing
    // other deprecated cases...
};
```

It is ambiguous about the 'playing'.
I don't know how to write to distinguish both of the '.playing'.

[image: both type of 'playing']

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to answer the question in the title. "K" means an enum case (they don't use "C" because it's used for "class" already). "V" means a `var` (or `let`), i.e. a property.

The Objective-C enum gets treated like this in Swift:

```
// This is not real Swift code, for illustrative purposes only
enum BJVPlayerStatus : Int {
    // This was BJVPlayerStatus_playing
    case playing
    // ...

    // This was BJVPlayerStatus_Playing
    @available(*, deprecated, message: "use `BJVPlayerStatus_playing`")
    var playing: BJVPlayerStatus {
        return BJVPlayerStatus.playing // returns the *case* .playing
    }
    // ...
}
```

The point here is that the deprecated `BJVPlayerStatus_Playing` is treated as a computed property in Swift, rather than an enum case, hence the "V". This is because you wrote

```
BJVPlayerStatus_Playing = BJVPlayerStatus_playing
```

in your Objective-C code.

Anyway, both the uppercase and lowercase name translates to `playing` in Swift, and that causes the conflict. You need to either:

- use separate header files for the Swift and Objective-C code, so the Swift code doesn't see the deprecated cases, or
- rename the *Swift name* for the deprecated case to something else using `NS_SWIFT_NAME`.

  ```
    BJVPlayerStatus_Playing NS_SWIFT_NAME(deprecatedPlaying) DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE("use `BJVPlayerStatus_playing`") = 
        BJVPlayerStatus_playing
  ```

Comment: Pretty cool! I just know it's conflict  due to the same name 'playing'. But you give me more detail information and another solution.  It's very helpful for me. I appreciate your answer.